# Inexpensive generation of hierarchical unique IDs

Tags: algorithms, performance, concepts, trees

My application is building a hierarchical structure like this:

```
root = { 
  'id': 'root',
  'children': [ {
    'name': 'root_foo',
    'children': []
  }, {
    'id': 'root_foo2',
    'children': [ {
      'id': 'root_foo2_bar',
      'children': []
      } ]
  } ]
}
```

in other words, it's a tree of nodes, where each node might have child elements and unique identifier I call "id". When a new child is added, I need to generate a unique identifier for it, however I have two problems:

- *identifiers are getting too long*
- *adding many children takes slower, as I need to find first available id*

My requirement is:

- *naming of a child X must be determined only from the state in their ancestors*
- *When I re-generate tree with same contents, the IDs must be same*

or in other words, when we have nodes A and B, creating child in A, must not affect the name given to children of B.

I know that one way to optimize would be to introduce counter in each node and append it to the names which will solve my performance issue, but will not address the issue with the "long identifiers".

**Could you suggest me the algorithm for quickly coming up with new IDs?**

Comment: Can you just generate a GUID as an ID? I know it's long, but it doesn't rely on a thing.

Comment: Can you expand on the long identifiers issue? What is considered long and why is it a problem?

Comment: @Vic: The thing is, when I re-generate the tree (I use this in web application) then identifiers must be the same. I added this to my question.

Comment: @TamásSzelei Long would be 60+ characters. Since I pass some of the identifiers through HTTP GET arguments, there are certain security plugins which won't let me do that.

Comment: Do nodes have data besides other children?

Comment: Also, you are probably building the tree in a deterministic order, why not just use a counter as an id?

Comment: how about creating id only when it's necessary, e.g. on the fly. each element in this structure already has unique access path e.g 0-1-1 representing position in each subsequent children array.

Comment: @TamásSzelei: yes, nodes have other data too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if children are ordered, then you can use the following schema:

- empty string means the root
- `1.0.3` means the fourth child of the first child of the second child of the root.

It is short, allows you to fetch a node from its ID, is unique, and is hierachical. It is a kind of [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: But in theory the sequence would still get too long, right?

Comment: Maybe if we md5('1.0.3.....') it would give us identifiers of consistent length...

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. I was going to suggest something along those lines (if the counter is not sufficient for some reason).

Comment: @romaninsh  
yes, hashing will give you consistant length. but you will loose the ability to use the name to fetch the item. It depends on what you want to do with this id.

Comment: Such names can obviously be shortened. For instance, using Base-36, and by dropping the `.`.  So `1A2` instead of `1.10.2`.

Comment: @MSalters but then you are limited to a given number of children per node.

Comment: If that's a problem you can add escape characters for that. E.g. `1A\2` would mean `1.362`. Logically, that's the opposite of a dot: you signal that the next character _does_ belong to the previous character: an un-separator if you will. Note that his ID strings were "long". You can't have 50 levels with 50 children at each level.

Comment: I think I'll hash them. Thanks everyone for suggestions!